# Java split() method confusion

Tags: java, split

I don't understand why it works this way - see below use cases of split() method.

```
    String x = "one,";
    String y = ",one";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.split(","))); //prints [one]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y.split(","))); //prints [, one]
```

I expeected them to print [one, ] and [, one].

Comment: try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.split(",", -1))); //prints [one, ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc of `split` answers that :

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

`x.split(",",-1)` will result in `[one, ]`.